# Can I convert a PS3 Skyrim savegame to a PC savegame?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

A few months ago I built a gaming pc and now I thougth I could try skyrim on it. I already played skyrim on my ps3 A LOT and I would love to continue my savegame.

So I am looking for a way to convert my ps3 save game to a pc savegame.

I searched for about half an hour for an answer  and found multiple videos describing how to do it BUT all of them were using "Skyrim ps3 toolkit" a program that decrypts the savegame I guess. It is just impossible to find that program now, everythin I can find are dead links or site with "this download was taken down".

Is there a other way to do this? or does someone now where I can still find that program?

btw I tried directly putting the PS3 savegame in to the savegame folder on my pc and it gives me the message "Could not be loaded. Save has version 0 this is version 9" or something like that.

Ask me anything if you need more information. I would be really happy about some help! :D cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you can't directly port a PS3 save is that the save file is encrypted. The toolkit you mentioned is designed specifically to decrypt that file to let your modify it and re-encrypt it, or simply use it in the PC version.

Unfortunately, the toolkit you needed has dropped off the face of the Internet, but I was able to [find it here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/eqizietgzawdt22/Skyrim.rar).

Once you have the application, you can then follow one of the many tutorials, like [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B6dgM-ZeX3M&feature=youtu.be) to walk you through the process of decrypting the save file.